# printing coupons in linux

Tags: wine, printing

I need to print coupons from websites such as coupons.com but, the website doesn't allow me to print using Linux. Is there any way around this? I heard that I can possibly do this by downloading User Agent Switcher? the download for the program needed to print these coupons is windows and mac os only.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/108384/how-can-i-execute-couponprinter-exe-to-print-coupon-com-coupons and https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wine/+question/128073

Comment: I know this is an old post, but Coupons.com has changed their website. It now works with Linux. It treats it like a mobile device, and sends you a code that you must enter, in order to print.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Their website says it is not possible to print in virtual environments, but I just did that and I can confirm that it works:
[image]

So how to print from coupons.com in linux:

1. install virtualization software (I did it with virtualbox)
2. install windows in the virtual environment
3. install your printer in the virtual windows
4. install their coupon printing software and happily print the coupons
5. don't forget to complain to them about not supporting linux

I didn't try, but it might also work with wine.

Comment: Gratz on VMing it :) but wine will not work. See https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wine/+question/128073

Comment: I tried with a new version of wine (installed windows version of firefox and the plugin) - it "works", however it refuses to print since it does some extra printer checking and it detects something fishy. I guess it would work with a hacked or a more sophisticated wine printer driver.